# Comparing and finding element of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say i have a list

`tab1={{0.378377, 1.58249*10^-11}, {0.44749, 1.03208*10^-13}, {0.513543,  2.13122*10^16}, {0.505355, 7.12295*10^16}}`

and i would like to find the element of the list that when the number gets bigger than one for the first time. In this case it is the 2.13122*10^16. Then i would like the give me the point where this happens in this case 0.513543.
I tried using If but i could not do it correctly.
I appreciate your help and your effort.

Best regards

Agapi

Comment: `Select[tab1, #[[2]] > 1 &][[1, 1]]` or `SelectFirst[tab1, #[[2]] > 1 &][[1]]`

Answer (score 2):

*Conversion of @Bob Hanlon's comment to an answer:*

```
SelectFirst[tab1, #[[2]] > 1 &][[1]]
```

*Explanation:*

`SelectFirst[list, f]` chooses the first element of the `list` such that `f` applied to that element yields `True`. (In this case, elements `f` will be applied to elements like `f[{0.378377, 1.58249*10^-11}]`.) In this answer, `#[[2]] > 1 &` is the function which looks at the second part of its argument, and returns `True` iff that part is greater than `1`. So, `SelectFirst[tab1, #[[2]] > 1 &]` returns `{0.513543,  2.13122*10^16}`, and then the final `[[1]]` takes the first element of that, i.e. `0.513543`.

Welcome to MMA SE!

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to choose form the same list the last element which is <1  in this case {0.44749, 1.03208*10^-13}

Comment: One simple way is to use `Reverse[list]` and then apply the same method. Another way is to use the more general `Select[tab1, #[[2]] > 1 &]`, which will give you a list of all such elements meeting the criteria (not just the first one), and then take the last element of this list, either by `Last[...]` or `...[[-1]]`.